# Vue: object has changed twice in father component but only triggered `deep watch` once in child component

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

I have nested components in my project: and I want to communciate between two components through an array object `activeGiftList`

Father component view:

```
    <div
      id="giftContainer"
      class="giftList"
      @click="hideBoard"
    >
      <template
        v-for="(item, index) in activeGiftList"
      >
        <send-gift-message
          v-if="item"
          :key="item.giftId"
          :gift-item="item"
          :gift-index="index"
          @changeActiveGiftList="changeActiveGiftList"/>
      </template>
    </div>
```

Father component js:

```
 watch: {
   activeGiftList: {
      handler: function (n) {
        if (n) {
          console.log('father: watch obj', n)
        }
      },
      deep: true
    }
 }
```

Children component:

```
  props: {
    giftItem: {
      type: Object,
      default: () => {
        return {}
      }
    },
    giftIndex: {
      type: Number,
      default: 0
    }
  },
  data () {
    return { flag: false }
  },
  watch: {
    giftItem: {
      handler: function (val, oldVal) {
        if (val) {
          this.flag = true
          console.log('child: watch obj', val)
        }
      },
      immediate: true,
      deep: true
    }
  },
  created () {
    console.log(this.flag, 'step 1')
  },
  mounted () {
    console.log(this.flag, 'step 2')
    setTimeout(() => {
      console.log(this.flag, 'step 3')
    }, 500)
  },
```

I have changed `this.activeGiftList` twice: 
first: [] => [{...}]  // changed by posting a request

second: [{...}] => // use `find` methods of array to pick up the target object and add one more properties on it,then use `$set` to cover original object via the same `index`

here is `console.log` result:

```
father: watch obj, [{...}]
child: watch obj, {...}
false, step 1
false, step 2
father: watch obj, [{...}] // add one property on it.
true, step 3
```

I'm quite confused even if I have used `deep` in vue watcher, and using `this.$set(this.activeGiftList, 0, newObj)` to cover original object in array to trigger secont change, but still can't watch the second change in children component. And can't get changes from new property in child component DOM.

Also I have tried change exist property of the same object, and child component seems changing the same times as the father component,Is there any good ideas to help me solve this problem?

Comment: `<send-gift-message ... @changeActiveGiftList="changeActiveGiftList"/>` is a bit odd. Should it not be `@change="changeActiveGiftList"`?

Comment: In this case I'm not using `changeActiveGiftList` to emit changes in father component, I just have two functions in father component that changes the `activeGiftList` array object proactively.  Maybe `changeActiveGiftList` should have nothing to do with this .